# How to get a regular iterator from an asynchronous iterator?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, iterator

Got an async iterable. Need a regular iterable.

```
asyc def aiter2iter(aiter):
    l = []
    async for chunk in aiter:
        l.append(chunk)
    return l

regular_iterable = await aiter2iter(my_async_iterable)
for chunk in regular_iterable:
    print('Hooray! No async required here!')
```

Is this the way to go or am I reinventing the wheel?

Is there any way provided by Python to convert an async iterable to a regular iterable?

Also is what I wrote even correct? Did I not miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your way works alright.  I would also try [`unsync`](https://github.com/alex-sherman/unsync) when working between async/sync functions.

**Given**

```
import time
import random
import asyncio

from unsync import unsync
```

```
# Sample async iterators
class AsyncIterator:
    """Yield random numbers."""

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        return random.randint(0, 10)


async def anumbers(n=10):
    """Yield the first `n` random numbers."""
    i = 0

    async for x in AsyncIterator():

        if i == n:
            return
        yield x
        i +=1
```

**Code**

Rather than awaiting and reiterating the result, we can just call the `result()`:

```
@unsync
async def aiterate(aiter):
    """Return a list from an aiter object."""
    return [x async for x in aiter]


aiterate(anumbers(5)).result()
# [8, 2, 5, 8, 9]
```

---

**Details**

Here's a description, from Python Byte's [episode 73](https://pythonbytes.fm/episodes/transcript/73/this-podcast-comes-in-any-color-you-want-as-long-as-it-s-black):

> You just take any async function, and put an `@unsync` decorator. ... it will basically wrap it up and do all that asyncio initialization stuff ...  then you can wait on the result, or not wait on the result, however you like. ... then if you put that on a regular function, not an async one, it'll cause it to run on a thread pool thread, on thread pool executor.